# How to use FORECAST function of OBIEE with my Calendar dimension?

Tags: oracle, analysis, obiee, oracle-bi

I want to use OBIEE forecast function that uses revenue column as a measure. 
Here is the code:

```
FORECAST("Остатки по бал. сч."."Прибыль (4-5)", ("Календарь"."Год","Календарь"."Месяц"), 'forecast', 'modelType=arima;numPeriods=3;predictionInterval=70;')
```

However error occurs that says

```
Invalid Time Dimension Argument Type specified for FORECAST() function. Argument type "Saldo"."D3 Calendar"."CAL_YEAR" should be of type Time Dimension. (HY000)
```

I dont understand why it can not use other than Time dimension just because the name of it different. Maybe I am wrong, can someone suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension you use must be a properly formed time dimension. Check out the official blog post and examples, they're pretty clear about it:
https://blogs.oracle.com/analyticscloud/using-forecast-function-in-oracle-dv-obiee-12c
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/data-visualization-2954126.html

Comment: You were right, thank you, there were some mistakes in my time dimension